# change the font size only for the table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I was wondering to know how to change the font size of the words, symbol , etc. only for the table and keep the size of  the text unchanged.

```
\begin{landscape}
 \fontsize{8pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\footnotesize
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\hline
Case & R.T.\footnote{Rock Type} & R.M. \footnote{Rock Mineralogy}& OABN \footnote{Oil Acid/Base Number} & Aging (days) & I.S (ppm)\footnote{Ionic Strength} & ObP(psi) \footnote{Overburden Pressure} & $\Delta p (psi)$  \footnote{Pressure drop} & I.B.C\footnote{Injected Brine composition} & P.B.C\footnote{Produced Brine composition} & pH & T(${^\circ}$C) \footnote{Temperature} & R.F.(\%) \footnote{Recovery Factor}& Re.\footnote{Reference}\\
\hline \hline 
1 & S \footnote{Sandstone} & 30000 & 23 & 100 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Core flooding results}
\label{tab:4.1}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: As you do in your code snippet. Since the last is `\footnotesize` the table (all what is inside `landscape` environment) has this font size. :) Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: thanks alot Zarko . but when i change the numbers for the \fontsize  it will not have any effect on the size of that :)

Comment: please, provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` folows relevant packages in preamble and end with `\end{document}. Only with it we can see your problem. I don't see any reason that your claim hold!

Comment: try `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
11111111111 &   2222222222  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
` and you should see, that table has smaller font than main text.

Comment: @Zarko perhaps you should expand it into an answer?

Comment: @Moriambar, done, Thank you to encourage me, to expand my comment to answer!

Answer (score 2):

Let me expand my comment to an answer ... from the following example is clearly seen, that the font size declared inside of the table (and only in those table) is smaller than in the other text in document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document} 
\lipsum*[2] 
    \begin{table}[ht] 
    \centering 
    \footnotesize % this font size is valid only inside table environment
\begin{tabular}{cc} 
    \hline 
11111111111 & 2222222222 \\ 
11111111111 & 2222222222 \\
11111111111 & 2222222222 \\
11111111111 & 2222222222 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\lipsum*[3] 
\end{document}
```

[image]